# How to add a button in Feinstein Sliding Drawer for sliding left or right

Tags: android

I am using `Feinstein sliding drawer`. I want to create a `Button`, and on clicking it, the drawer opens.
In Feinstein sample project, it is in Action Bar. I want to do it without action bar.
Any idea?
Any help will be appreciated...
In general, I just want to call the slide action on its click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call the slide action by this code

```
if (getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()) {
getSlidingMenu().showContent();
} else {
getSlidingMenu().showMenu();
}
```

in your activity when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you tell me how to specify whether left drawer or right drawer opens?